# Checking strings for empty

Tags: java

Very tired this morning so if this is obvious then thats my excuse !!!

i am using a buffered reader to read through a csv file - but i dont want to add any empty spaces, as in

" "

the problem is - when i read the line i am checking if the string length is > 0, if so then add, however the string " " is of length 4 - even tho its empty

is there a better check i can do

thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
s.trim().isEmpty()
```

Answer (score 3):

could trim the input :-)

```
trim()
      Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.
```

karl

Answer (score 2):

I usually prefer, StringUtils of commons-lang, or something like that. Actually, you require this kinda check every now and then, plus there are few variants and all are null-safe. Namely, `StringUtils.isBlank(String str)`, `StringUtils.isNotBlank(String str)`, `StringUtils.isEmpty(String str)`, `StringUtils.isNotEmpty(String str)`, `StringUtils.trimToEmpty(String str)`, and `StringUtils.trimToNull(String str)`.

Comment: +1 for that - I use `StringUtils.defaultString()` (both the unary and binary versions) so often now that I feel it should be part of the language.